# Connect to Redis from Django view

Tags: python, django, redis

I found solution for connect django view to redis:

```
import redis

cacheDB = redis.StrictRedis()
cacheDB.sadd("new_post", post.id)
```

But when I add code to the view, my page loads with ~2 sec delay. Did it creates a new connect session on every request? Or maybe it's because of my Win7 test platform...

My modules: redis, redis_cache, django_redis.

in settings.py:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "redis_cache.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "127.0.0.1:6379:1",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "redis_cache.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}

SESSION_ENGINE = 'redis_sessions.session' # for djcelery
```

And nothing for redis in INSTALLED_APPS, mb i missed something here?

Comment: How long is the delay if you call `sadd` in `python manage.py shell`?

Comment: @ZZY When I call it the first time, a delay of about a second. Further attempts without delay.